# Proper way to send JSON data along with sendFile() with Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've setup a Node.js server with express and I've setup routing. When navigating to a specific location: "/users/id", I'm currently using sendFile(), but I'd also like to pass JSON data into the page.

I know I can serve the page and then make an ajax request on page load, but it seems like I would want to minimize server side calls as much as possible.

I would like to do something like below, but even if this works I'm not sure how to grab the data from the web page side. (If I'm not making a separate ajax call)

```
app.get('/'+element+'/:id', (request, response) => {
            const id = request.params.id;
            pool.query('SELECT * FROM '+element+' WHERE id = ?', id,(error, result)=>{
            if(error) throw error;
            response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname+'/../html/index.html'));
            response.json({message: result.name});
            });
        });
```

I'd like to return the data and the file and I'd like to know how to grab the data if I send it at the same time as the file.

Comment: FYI, your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  I'd recommend whitelisting that table name anyway.

Comment: What I think you're asking is how to send a static page with dynamic data embedded into it.  Is that correct?  I understand the desire to reduce server-side calls once that page has loaded, but do you have a particular reason to do that?  It's often better for performance to send that static page so it can be cached, and then just fetch the data on future page loads.

Comment: ```const urlPaths = {
    USERS: 'users'
};
for(let element in urlPaths)```
I'm pulling the table names from a enum set rn, is that what you meant by white listing? I can definitely run with what I have now. It was as much a question of "how can I do it" as it was "is this best practice to have multiple calls"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to to accommodate a simple string for the example you've given, you might consider accomplishing this through a response header. While it's not the most conventional approach, it might be the easiest in your case.

```
app.get('/' + element + '/:id', function(request, response, next) {
  let id = request.params.id;
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM ' + element + ' WHERE id = ?', id, (error, result) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    let options = {
      dotfiles: 'deny',
      headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true,
        'x-result-message': result.name // your custom header here
      }
    }
    let fileName = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../html/index.html')
    response.sendFile(fileName, options, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        next(err)
      } else {
        console.log('Sent:', fileName)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my code snippet was a little off.. I've updated it to better reflect my question.

Comment: See my edited answer - not the most conventional approach but might be easiest to accomplish what you're after by mixing file and content in one execution.